# is there way to pass value in Rg.Plugin.Popup popupNavigation?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

is there way to pass value in Rg.Plugin.Popup popupNavigation?

I have a page, with a button. if clicked, I want to open custom popup page, with passing a ID value

```
CustomPopupPage _CustomPopupPage = new CustomPopupPage();
PopupNavigation.Instance.Pushing += (sender, e) => Debug.WriteLine($"[Popup] Pushing: {e.Page.GetType().Name}");

var ID = "5";
await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(_CustomPopupPage);
```

custompopuppage class - here i want Get the ID and do something with it

```
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class CustomPopupPage : Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage
    {
     ...
    }
```

Comment: pass it in the constructor, or via a public property or method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason's reply, you can pass value in Popup page's constructor, For example, this is the Popup Page.

```
 public partial class popup1 : PopupPage
{
    string parameter;
    public popup1(string str)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
      //get pass value from contentpage,
        parameter = str;
    } 
}
```

Pass value from ContentPage.

```
  private async void btnPopupButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new popup1("parameter Id"));
    }
```

Comment: If Using Prism Simple Use the  *NavigationParameters*